# Finding the date of a data point in a R time-series

Tags: r, time-series

I make a time series:

> t = ts(rnorm(12*50), start=1900, freq=12)

and then find the maximum with `max(t)`. Is there any convenient way to find out what date this maximum occurred at?

Comment: Try `?which`. E.g. `which(t == max(t))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `which.max()` which works for many object types, including `ts` as in your example:

```
R> set.seed(42); tser <- ts(rnorm(12*2), start=2010, freq=12)
R> which.max(tser)
[1] 12                              ## so index 12 is suggsted
R> tser[12]                         ## what is its value?       
[1] 2.28665                         ## 2.28665 -- indeed the max.
R> tser                             
            Jan        Feb        Mar        Apr        May
2010  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683
2011 -1.3888607 -0.2787888 -0.1333213  0.6359504 -0.2842529
            Jun        Jul        Aug        Sep        Oct
2010 -0.1061245  1.5115220 -0.0946590  2.0184237 -0.0627141
2011 -2.6564554 -2.4404669  1.3201133 -0.3066386 -1.7813084
            Nov        Dec
2010  1.3048697  2.2866454
2011 -0.1719174  1.2146747
R>
```

If you convert from `ts` to, say, `zoo` you even get the meta-data displayed:

```
R> zser <- as.zoo(tser)
R> which.max(zser)
[1] 12
R> zser[12]
2010(12) 
 2.28665 
R>
```

That shows the Dec 2010 label for the data point with the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I wanted. The zoo version especially.